# android- bitmap drawable as background image to fill screen but keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, background, drawable, scaling

I cant figure out how to use a bitmap as background image in a way that it is scaled to fill the screen but keeps the aspect ratio. So far I have only found the solution that I use an additional ImageView instead of a background image and use android:scaleType="centerCrop"

```
...
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
/>
...
```

Nevertheless I would prefer to solve this by setting the activity background on the window

```
 <style ...>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
```

as I was told (and see) that this is much faster. (@drawable/background being a XML drawable)

Seems like such a common task yet I cant find a solution so far. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

martin

Comment: `background` is a PNG file, right?

Comment: right now a xml drawable with a jpg src

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set adjustViewBounds property to true ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aravind and sorry for my question to be unclear. The thing is I dont want to use ImageView if possible.

Comment: If that is the case, you can resize the image by overriding onMeasure & onDraw methods. Or you can directly use the canvas widget which allows you to draw the image with the specified size.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem a number of times in my projects and each time due to lack of time (and laziness) I would be satisfied with a less than optimum solution. But recently I found some time to crack down this particular issue. Here is my solution and I hope it helps you as well.

```
Bitmap scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(Bitmap image)
        {
            int imaheVerticalAspectRatio,imageHorizontalAspectRatio;
            float bestFitScalingFactor=0;
            float percesionValue=(float) 0.2;

            //getAspect Ratio of Image
            int imageHeight=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getHeight()/100)*100);
            int imageWidth=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getWidth()/100)*100);
            int GCD=BigInteger.valueOf(imageHeight).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(imageWidth)).intValue();
            imaheVerticalAspectRatio=imageHeight/GCD;
            imageHorizontalAspectRatio=imageWidth/GCD;
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image Dimensions(W:H): "+imageWidth+":"+imageHeight);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image AspectRatio(W:H): "+imageHorizontalAspectRatio+":"+imaheVerticalAspectRatio);

            //getContainer Dimensions
            int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int displayHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
           //I wanted to show the image to fit the entire device, as a best case. So my ccontainer dimensions were displayWidth & displayHeight. For your case, you will need to fetch container dimensions at run time or you can pass static values to these two parameters 

            int leftMargin = 0;
            int rightMargin = 0;
            int topMargin = 0;
            int bottomMargin = 0;
            int containerWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);
            int containerHeight = displayHeight - (topMargin + bottomMargin);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Container dimensions(W:H): "+containerWidth+":"+containerHeight);

            //iterate to get bestFitScaleFactor per constraints
            while((imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor <= containerWidth) && 
                    (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor<= containerHeight))
            {
                bestFitScalingFactor+=percesionValue;
            }

            //return bestFit bitmap
            int bestFitHeight=(int) (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
            int bestFitWidth=(int) (imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitScalingFactor: "+bestFitScalingFactor);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitOutPutDimesions(W:H): "+bestFitWidth+":"+bestFitHeight);
            image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bestFitWidth,bestFitHeight, true);

            //Position the bitmap centre of the container
            int leftPadding=(containerWidth-image.getWidth())/2;
            int topPadding=(containerHeight-image.getHeight())/2;
            Bitmap backDrop=Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth, containerHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas can = new Canvas(backDrop);
            can.drawBitmap(image, leftPadding, topPadding, null);

            return backDrop;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution - i havent developed for android for over one year so i dont have the setup right now to try your solution yet i hope it helps other beings around - thanks again